# trigonometry law of cosines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> A triangular parcel of ground has sides of lengths $725$ft, $650$ft, and $575$ft. Find the measure of the largest angle.

It's obvious that the largest angle is the one opposite $725$ft side, and using law of cosines the angle could be either (approximately) $72.281^\circ$ or $107.719^\circ$.

I thought that both would be the answer because the other angles too ($58.652^\circ$ and $49.067^\circ$) and $(58.652^\circ$ and $13.629^\circ$) make sense to me.

However, it turns out that only $72.281^\circ$ is the answer. Why then isn't the other triangle an answer?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way should get two solutions. Set $c=725$, $a=650$, $b=575$ and the law of cosines:

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos \gamma$$

And solve for $\cos\gamma$:

$$\cos\gamma = {a^2+b^2-c^2\over 2ab}\approx 0.304$$

Solving then for $\gamma$ gives:

$$\gamma = \pm\cos^{-1}{a^2+b^2-c^2\over 2ab} + 2n\pi \approx \pm 1.262+2n\pi \approx \pm72.28^\circ + n 360^\circ$$

Obviously the negative of $\pm$ and $n$ other than $0$ are out of range.

Also geometrically we know that the angles are uniquely determined by the length of the sides due to congruence.

The error you probably did was to confuse the general solution to equations of the form $\sin v=A$ and $\cos v=A$.